# Firestore, detecting a new document added to a collection, and more

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Listening to documents changes on a Firestore Document is quite easy and works well.

I'm wondering though if there's any way to listen to a collection in a way we get notified when a document belonging to this collection is added/updated/deleted.

So far we can know everything that happens to a known document, but of course if it's a new document we definitely have no way to create in advance a listener on this document. Moreover, even if we were able to know in advance the new documents IDs, it's obvious that creating as many listeners as documents we have in a collection would be absolutely a bad practice.

My question in not specific to any language but for information I'm using flutter.

Does Firestore ecosystem provide a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> if it's a new document we definitely have no way to create in advance a listener on this document

That's not really true.  You can construct a query that *would* yield a document before that document exists.  A listener on that query will show the document as added in the event that it's created, and also satisfies the constraints of the query.

I don't know if flutter has very good documentation for this, but [the core documentation for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) shows how you can get snapshot changes when the results of a query change.  Note that you can check the resulting query snapshot for documents that have been added, removed, or changed since the prior snapshot that was delivered to the listener.

The trick is to come up with a query that will tell you what you want to know.  You will have to populate the document with enough information so that a listener can tell that it's a document of interest that was just created.

Comment: Thanks, I think you oriented me to the right track. I have something like that : 

Collection 'messenger'  > Docs 'conversations' > Collection 'thread' > Docs 'messages'.  

'thread' has a property 'users' which is an array containing the 2 users uids.
My query is filtering by user id being inside users array, and my purpose is to get any change on the thread.

For now, I have that :  fb.collection('messages').where('users', arrayContains: uid).snapshots()

I'm absolutely not sure it's possible to build a query that will be able to detect a change on a single message, a message added

Comment: New documents that satisfy that query will show up as "added" in the query snapshot. You should be able to detect that in your listener.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to be the case, I tried id and I got only notifications about the changes on the parent collection. Please note that I have actually a collection containing documents that contain collections that contain documents. My temporary workaround is to add a field 'lastupdated' to the parent collection and updating this field as soon as a message is created, then I can observe the collection itself and I know a change occurred.

Comment: You definitely get called back for documents in a collection that are newly added.  Without seeing your specific code and database structure, it's not possible to say what's going on.  But the fact that you said "parent collection" leads me to believe that you might be expecting documents to appear in a query that isn't looking at the collection that it's targeting.  A query can only look at a single collection at a time.  A query will not consider "a parent collection" for matching documents.

Comment: " A query can only look at a single collection at a time." This is the fact I was not sure about. Sorry if my question was not clear. As you guessed I was trying to detect every change occurring in a child collection. To be more precise :  My structure is like that :  Collection A > Documents > Collection B<i> > Documents.   My purpose was to know about both new documents created in A and new documents created in the B<i> collections.  Now, thanks to your answer I know it's not possible, so I will keep my workaround alive. Thank you so much for your appreciated help Doug!